# Altium: Parameter from 'Sheet Symbol' in Schematic also displayed on PCB?

Tags: altium

As image below, I have a 'Sheet Symbol' that I will use many times. I have defined a parameter for the 'Sheet Symbol' called 'name'. Is there a way of having this text shown on the overlay/silkscreen of the PCB 'automatically'. To prevent me from having to type out the text again? but also for tighter synchronism between PCB and SCH?.

The only thing I can think of is making a fake symbol called 'PCB_LABEL', where I just utilise say the comments parameter, to achieve the same result, albiet less elegantly.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should post Tool specific questions in respective Tools' forum for better responses. For eg: Altium has a live forum of discussion. You will get all tool specific answers there.

Comment: yes, a better chance of good answer, but I like to support the use of StackExchange, the 'system' is superior IMO

Answer (score 1):

You can place strings with any parameter by setting the string text to .name.

The string should be in a room or inside a component in order to get the parameter from the schematic.

I recommend changing from **name** to something more specific, **name** could be a reserved string.

Answer (score 0):

The buzzword you are looking for is "Specialstrings". They are defined well in the documentation and work as already mentioned here.

However you should surely change the parameter to at least something like my_name or similar, as to generic words are usually either occupied or forbidden...